# How to validate access token with implicit flow on backend?

Tags: authentication, implicit-flow

I didn't make such decisions with implicit flow (I know it's not so good to use it), but I currently have situation where I have to validate my access token on backend(Java 8). Is it okay for every request with access token additionally call `oidc` provider to check if token is active(not revoked, with valid lifetime) or there is more appropriate way how to handle it? Anyway thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your scenario?

Comment: Angular(12) application make authorize call to oidc provider, after successful authentication, angular app has access token and idtoken. Puts access token in http interceptor to Authorization Bearer header to every request. When backend gets such access token in Authorization header, what is the best approache to validate this access token?

Comment: Alex have u found a method?